# Entropy of intervening variable in Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, information-theory, entropy

Let's assume we are given discrete random variables $X$, $Z$, with some nonzero mutual information $I[X,Z] > 0$. I would like to understand the minimum entropy of  variables $Y$ such that $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain. By the data processing inequality, $H[Y] \geq I[X,Z]$. But can we also find some $Y$ for which this bound is close to tight, that is $H[Y]$ close to $I[X,Z]$?

More formally: Let $F$ be the set of variables $Y$ such that $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain. Can we upper-bound $\inf_{Y\in F} H[Y]$ in relation to $I[X,Z]$?
Or are there conditions under which such an upper bound holds?
I'd be interested in any kind of upper bound on $\inf_{Y\in F} H[Y]$, even if it is much larger than $I[X,Z]$, as long as it is better than $\inf_{Y\in F} H[Y] \leq H[X], H[Z]$.

I have looked around the web but didn't find anything related. Any pointers (or an explanation why this isn't possible) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking at the Wyner common information. Check out https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1055346 , in particular the subsection marked 'second approach' on pg 164 (and, for that matter, the rest of the paper, it's quite nice). Wyner also mentions conditions for $H(Y) = I(X;Z)$ to hold, and there's another paper of Witsenhausen that may be interesting. I'm not sure if there are better bounds than the trivial ones above but given the time there must be progress on this. In any case the keyword should help you find an answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I just remembered - a mid 2010s paper of Anantharam and Kamath did some fun stuff with hypercontractivity over the Gray-Wyner system. This might also be germane, esp. regarding better bounds.